# Is it normal for Tokio to open this many threads/processes?

Tags: asynchronous, unix, rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

Is it normal for Tokio to open this many threads?

```
top - 19:50:25 up  5:55,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Threads:   9 total,   0 running,   9 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  19963.7 total,  19046.5 free,    268.3 used,    648.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.  19449.8 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   1665 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 nfwd                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   1666 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tokio-runtime-w                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1667 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tokio-runtime-w                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1668 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tokio-runtime-w                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1669 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tokio-runtime-w                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1670 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tokio-runtime-w                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1671 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tokio-runtime-w                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1672 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tokio-runtime-w                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1673 root      20   0   17556      4      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tokio-runtime-w
```

All I'm doing is using the `tokio::net::UnixListener` to listen on a socket. But as you can see in `top` Tokio has opened 8 different processes/threads named `tokio-runtime-w`.

What is causing this, it is necessary to have this many and can it be limited/omited?

```
pub struct StreamServer {
    pub socket: UnixListener,
}

impl StreamServer {
    pub async fn new() -> Result<Self, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let directory = temp_dir();

        let path = directory.as_path().join("d");
        if path.exists() {
            remove_file(&path).await?;
        }

        let socket = UnixListener::bind(&path)?;
        Ok(Self { socket })
    }

    pub async fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        loop {
            match &self.socket.accept().await {
                Ok((stream, addr)) => loop {
                    match &self.stream.readable().await {
                        Ok(()) => {
                            let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(1024);

                            match &self.stream.try_read_buf(&mut buf) {
                                Ok(n) => {
                                    let msg = String::from_utf8((&buf.as_slice()[..*n]).to_vec())?;
                                    Ok((msg, *n))
                                }
                                Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
                                    Ok(("".to_string(), 0))
                                }
                                Err(e) => todo!("{:?}", e),
                            }
                        }
                        Err(e) => todo!("{:?}", e),
                    }
                },
                Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
                    continue;
                }
                Err(_) => todo!(),
            };
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {    
    let mut stream = StreamServer::new().await?;
    stream.run().await?;
}
```

Comment: @cafce25 True, updated with text only.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, this looks like a normal result.

There are a fixed number of [`worker_threads`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.worker_threads):

> The default value is the number of cores available to the system.

And a dynamic number of [`blocking_threads`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.max_blocking_threads):

> The default value is 512.

You can configure the `Runtime` using the methods linked above, or `worker_threads` is configurable [in the attribute](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/attr.main.html) like so:

```
#[tokio::main(worker_threads = 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Will my code above actually utilize the 2 threads if I set them?

Comment: @Nikk you appear to only have a single asynchronous thread of execution but tokio itself has other tasks that help drive I/O operations and timers. So yes, but you could also just use [the single-threaded runtime](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/attr.main.html#using-current-thread-runtime) if the thread resources are a problem.